# How can I write the argument name from Python argparse to a file?

Tags: python, argparse, with-statement

I want to use argparse to write the argument names & values it receives to a file. I have this so far:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--infile", help = "seed file", default = 'test')
parser.add_argument("--lang", help="wiki language bigram", default = 'en')
parser.add_argument("--request_type", help="request type", default = 'sum')
parser.add_argument("--outfile", help = "path to outfile", default = 'outfile')
parser.add_argument("--summary", help = "true or false", action = "store_true")
parser.add_argument("--pagehits", help = "path to list of page hits", default = 'pagehits')
parser.add_argument("--exemplar_file", help = "file to inspire book")

args = parser.parse_args()

input_file = args.infile
print(args.infile)
print(var(args))

with open('modified-variables', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(args.infile)
    outfile.write('hello world')
```

with --infile "/path/to/file" --lang "en" output is:

```
/path/to/file
en

[but nothing written to file]
```

I want it to loop over all the positional parameters and write all those that are supplied in the command line to modified-variables in the format

```
infile="/path/to/file"
lang="en"
```

Googling is not helping me figure out how to print the argnames and there is something simple wrong in the with/write construct.

UPDATE: added print(vars((args)) per answer #1 which yields:

```
{'lang': 'en', 'exemplar_file': None, 'pagehits': 'pagehits', 'summary': False, 'outfile': '/tmp/pagekicker/123/out_test', 'request_type': 'sum', 'infile': '/home/fred/pagekicker-community/scripts/seeds/revolutionary-figures'}
```

Now I just want to write

lang="en"
exemplar_file="None"

etc.

to a file.

Comment: Why are you calling `parse_args` twice?

Comment: that's an error, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
print(args)    # the default Namespace display format
```

or

```
print(vars(args))
```

`vars(args)` is a dictionary, which you can display in a number of different ways.   You could convert it to a list of tuples (`.items()`), you could iterate over the `keys`, etc.